# Jquery DateTimePicker Timezone flag creates incorrect/duplicate date on Mac?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have bumped into a weird error on Mac when using the Jquery datetime picker widget. The widget works fine on all Windows browsers but on any browser on Mac it shows a duplicate date when I include the 'T' Timezone flag in my date format.

When I run this on any Windows browser (Chrome,Firefox,IE) the value and date display fine in the input box. Example: **Tue, 6 Jan 2015 12:41:48 PST**

```
$("#launch_date").datetimepicker({
        format : "D, j M Y G:i:s T"
});
```

However; the same code run on any browser (Safari, Chrome) on Mac displays: **Tue, 6 Jan 2015 13:02:23 Tue Jan 06 2015 13:02:23 GMT-0800 (PST)**

if I remove the "T" timezone flag it does not display a duplicate date. I need the timezone to be on dates selected. Is there a different way to format the date on Mac vs Windows?

Comment: Try using `showTimezone: true` not sure if that will work

Comment: Tried that and didn't seem to work. Also I stand corrected the date is actually: "Tue, 6 Jan 2015 13:02:23 Tue Jan 06 2015 13:02:23 GMT-0800 (PST)" On Mac. That Timezone flag must flag something else  on mac.

Comment: I ended up implementing the Bootstrap date picker which works on both Windows and Mac but would be nice to know why this is happening on Mac.